# Scan all integers on a line into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to scan a line of Integers from a `txt` file and store them within an `ArrayList`. My question is simple, how can I do this?

This is what I have

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Integer> coinTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer i ;
    File f = new File (args[0]);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
       i = input.nextInt() ;
       input.nextLine();
       while(input.hasNextInt()) {
            if(input.hasNextLine()) {
               coinTypes.add(i);
            }
            if(input.hasNextLine()) {
               change = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Found change"); //used for debugging
                System.out.println("Change: " + change);
            }
       }
    System.out.println(coinTypes);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't what I have work?

**INPUT**:

```
java homework5 hwk5sample1.txt
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Found change
Change: 143
[1]
```

`Txt` file:

```
// Coins available in the USA, given in cents.  Change for $1.43?
1 5 10 25 50 100
143
```

**WANT**:

```
Change: 143
[1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]
```

Comment: You only read `i = input.nextInt();` once, outside of the loop, and yet add `coinTypes.add(i);` inside of the loop. You need to read the int inside the loop as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different problems in your code

```
if(input.hasNextLine()) {
    coinTypes.add(i);
}
```

That `if` is not required since you are checking that in the `while` before

The main problem is that you are not reading the input inside the loop ie

```
i = input.nextInt() ;
```

This should be inside the while loop.

And finally your `change` should not be put in that loop as change is a single value. If you keep it the loop change will be read every time the loop iterates. But if you keep it outside the loop another problem arise. ie the `change` will also be read after reading the coins to `coinTypes`.

#### Solution

```
input.nextLine();
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    i = input.nextInt();
    coinTypes.add(i);
}
int change = coinTypes.get(coinTypes.size()-1);
coinTypes.remove(coinTypes.size() - 1);
System.out.println("Change: " + change);
System.out.println(coinTypes);
```

After the loop `coinTypes` will have the change as the last item. I have removed that last item and kept the last item in `change` using these lines.

```
int change = coinTypes.get(coinTypes.size()-1);
coinTypes.remove(coinTypes.size() - 1);
```

#### Alternate Solution

```
ArrayList<Integer> coinTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer i;
File f = new File(args[0]);
Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

input.nextLine();
int change;
String[] coinsline = input.nextLine().split("\\s");
for(String coin: coinsline) {
    coinTypes.add(Integer.parseInt(coin));
}
change = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
System.out.println("change: " + change);
System.out.println(coinTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would open the file, read the first line and split it.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
      try {
          String[] numbers_= br.readLine().split(" ");
          int[] numbers = new int[numbers_.length]; //I don't remember if this could be done.
          for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
             numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt( numbers_[i] );
          }
      }
      finally {
        br.close();
      }
```

I think something like that should work =)

Comment: I apologize. Edited. :)